# Content Security Policy not present inside network tab of developer tools

Tags: javascript, html, security

I have included Content Security Policy meta tag inside head section but still I cant find it under network tab of developer tools. How to find it? I am using chrome version 76 and IE 11. Shall I include it in the form of meta tag inside html page or incorporate inside apache tomcat folder from the backend? Which one would be better?

Comment: If the header isn't visible in the devtools, chances are high you didn't correctly activate it in your server.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'> this is the meta tag

Comment: I'm not activating it in server instead i'm using meta tag - <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'>. Is this the correct solution?

Comment: Why would you expect to find that under the network tab in the devtools? It's not a header, it's a meta tag. Or is the problem that it doesn't even show up in the page source?

Comment: Okay.
Yes, it's there in the page source. In order for it to reflect in the dev tools, I need to activate it from server-side, right?

Comment: You mean in the header view on the network tab? Yes, for that you'll need to adjust the server configuration and/or code.